# Proper procedure for tag helpers in moustache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates, mustache

I've been reading over the moustache documentation, and it looks cool:
https://github.com/defunkt/mustache

There is a clear separation between ruby code and html markup.  Having not started a moustache project, my confusion is this: how should ruby that generates markup be handled?  Obvious examples would be form helpers and link_to, not to mention any custom methods.  Would it be proper (or possible) to do {{link_to ...}}? -- having code in the markup.  Or to define a custom method in the view ruby: {{whatever_link}}? -- this seems non-DRY and equally undesirable.  Where's the win?

Thanks!

--Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mustache is very simple by design. Templates are supposed to be renderable in many languages (see https://github.com/defunkt/mustache/wiki/Other-Mustache-implementations). Many web applications chose mustache because templates can be shared by client code (javascript) and server code (whatever language).

The win is not to go against that fact, even if it may look inconvenient at first sight.

Investigate the {{whatever_link}} solution, and keep *your* code as DRY as you can.

Comment: +1 Exactly this. Mustache forces you to keep anything that you could "get wrong" in the view. This makes it much easier to test, and, as Gwendal said, allows you to render your templates in any language (e.g. offload rendering to client-side JavaScript for browsers that support it).

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I do in mustache.java:

```java
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class UrlHelper implements Map<String, String> {

    public static final UrlHelper instance = new UrlHelper();
    private static final String NORMAL_PREFIX = "url";
    private final String virtualHost;

    // configure virtualhost here
    private UrlHelper() {           
        virtualHost = "/";
    }

    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return key.toString().indexOf(':') != -1;
    }

    public String get(Object key) {
        String k = key.toString();
        String prefix = k.substring(0, k.indexOf(':'));
        String url = k.substring(k.indexOf(":") + 1);
        if (prefix.equals(NORMAL_PREFIX))
            return virtualHost + url;
        return virtualHost + "static/" + prefix + "/" + url + "." + prefix;
    }
    // Default implementation for the other 'Map' methods
}
```

When rendering I do this:

```
mustache.execute(writer,new Object[] { model, UrlHelper.instance }).flush();
```

You can use like this(assume your app is hosted at /app):

```
{{js:lib/jquery}} {{! /app/static/js/lib/jquery.js }}
{{css:site}} {{! /app/static/css/site.css }}  
{{url:users/edit/1}} {{! /app/users/edit/1 }}
```

It is also possible to have a single prefix for all static resources(eg: static), but you can't use dots to specify the file extension, so you must use some other character to represent dots and replace in your processing code.

You can probably adapt this technique to your web framework/language.

Comment: that is a very neat trick to add params to mustache.java - i was looking for how to pass parameters in to helpers

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Gwendal that a goal of Mustache is to be able to share views between your backend and frontend, though that is not the only goal -- you might use Mustache if you just want to clean up things in your views. In that light, another way to think about Mustache is that it pushes the logic to the layer behind the immediate frontend (i.e. Ruby code). So in this middle layer you can do anything you want. I would recommend using the [stache](http://github.com/agoragames/stache) gem because it fills in the gap between Mustache-land and Rails-land by making a connection between your Mustache view class and the underlying Rails view class. So this way, you could use, for instance, `link_to` in this middle layer. You'd have to make a view method that wrapped a call to `link_to` for a particular object, since you can't call methods in a Mustache template and pass it arguments, but I think that is okay.